# parameters stability in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on JSP-servlet application and now I am programming a page which edit information about registrars.

The senario is that there's an `ArrayList` I send form servlet to JSP page when I load the page. The `ArrayList` contains information about groups the registrar belongs, the `ArrayList` is resulted after making multiple SQL statements. When user try to edit some fields and make one required field empty and submit the form, the servlet makes validation and return error to edit page.

The problem I face is that all the groups I sent in the first time fly in the sky. So I have to make connection to DB again and make multiple queries to get the groups again and send it back to JSP page.
Is there's another simple way to make arrayList stable in JSP page ?

**EDIT**
Here's the code which I make the scope of the  `ArrayList` in the session.

```
<c:set var="userGroups" value="${userGroups}" scope="session"></c:set>
```

Comment: @Piyush- I don't know Ajax, but if it works ,I really like to know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either store it in the session or just live with it. I really don't see any issues with that. If the concrete problem is that you have to copypaste the same code again or that the whole code is ugly to have in a Servlet class, then just refactor/hide that into an useable DAO class which you import/call/reuse in the Servlet the usual Java way.

---

**Update**: as per your update, this doesn't make sense. You just need to change your servlet code from

```
request.setAttribute("userGroups", userGroups);
```

to

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("userGroups", userGroups);
```

You don't need `<c:set>` for this.

Comment: I tried to store it in a session through making the scope of the variable as a session but it doesn't work, what do u mean by live with it?? The main problem I face is the multiple sql statements I make to get the ArrayList for the first time, and encapsulating the functions in a class it seems good idea , but DAO appreciation stands for what??

Comment: If it doesn't work, then you probably did something wrong. As to "just live with it", I mean to say "just accept it and move on". The DAO abbreviation stands for Data Access Object.

Comment: Thanx for this information, I'll put the code related to session scope, see the edit section plz.

Comment: See answer update. In the future, please comment *after* you actually edited the question. I didn't see anything at the time you posted the comment.

Comment: @BalusC- it's new information for me, and it works , maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaany thanx ,I really owe u much of my information, next time I'll make comments in the suitable place.